# Playing music on a Mac in lock screen and display off

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, sleep

I have an app with a behavior that I want to copy. The app can play music in the lock screen state. The app can also turn off the screen at this state. I'm not too sure if the app is placing the Mac in sleep mode but the white indicator light on the front of the Mac book is on but is not pulsing while the display is off.

I know how to play music and place the mac in the lock screen state using apple script. What I don't know how to do is turn off the display and have the indicator light turned on. This behavior is similar to when the Mac is in sleep mode. Any ideas as to how this can be done programmatically using objective-c and/or apple script?

I cannot use anything that is not documented by Apple. I am running the latest version of OSX Lion.

Comment: For what it's worth, a pulsating LED indicates that the computer is sleeping, and a fixed one indicates that only the display has been turned off. If you can't find an API, `pmset force displaysleep 1` from the command line will force a display sleep (in one minute - there may be a way to force "immediately") and not change the permanent settings. It may be worth wrapping that.

Comment: I just bought my Mac book a few months ago. When I force the laptop to sleep, the LED does not pulse but stays on constantly. Is there documentation that states this?

Comment: You may need to reset your MacBook's SMC... here's one thread I found -> http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1059303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold down the command, shift and eject buttons at the same time, the screen goes dark instantly.  I just confirmed this in 10.7.1.

As for Applescripting Display Sleep, it's not trivial.  I did find a probable solution in this thread:

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=135732#p135732

Give it a try and see if it accomplishes what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah perfect, that works. How would you do this when there is no eject button like on a Mac book air?

Comment: see if the second option I gave you works well on a MacBook Air.

Comment: Should be the power button. (Works on my Late 2013 MacBook Pro.)